# Do your damage effects last after your death?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, now that I've been playing a lot of pvp, I am starting to find my in the occasional position of being out of place and about to go down with no hope of healing.  In these situations, I really want to hand out the most hurt before I have to cool off in the med center. As I'm playing a bounty hunter, I normally can switch over to blow everything mode and max my heat out before I go down, but I can't seem to tell if my Explosive dart is sticking around after me or not. I know the rest of my abilities that have already resolved do (for example: If I light someone on fire, the effect resolves as normal regardless of my status). On a related note, do you earn damage points for stuff that resolves while you are dead, or do you lose those few ticks?

As applies to warzones, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, DoTs become effects on the target, so when you die they remain.

Haven't you died in PvE after you kill a mob but the DoT kills you? same thing in PvP.

Comment: I know about the dots, I'm talking about the effects that haven't actually resolved by the time you die, like explosive darts on the bounty hunter.

Comment: same thing, everything turns into an effect on the target, not on the origin. That's different than, say, a channeled attack, that only works as long as the caster is holding the attack. Those do disappear when the caster dies.